# How to make React loading indicator show after waiting short interval?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have a spinner that shows while data is loading - the code looks like this:

```
<Spinner show={this.props.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0} />
```

However, some of these AJAX calls finish so quickly the spinner fades in and out near instantly and it looks bad.  Is there anyway to add a delay before showing the spinner (e.g. 200ms) so if the call finishes before this time, no spinner is shown?  What would that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a little hack there. Maintain a component state, which keep track of, if the timer is over or not something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    if(newProps.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0 && !this.state.timerOver){
         setTimeout(() => { this.setState({timerOver: true});}, 200)
    }
    else if(newProps.ajaxCallsInProgress <= 0){
         this.setState({timerOver: false});
    }
}

render(){
    return(
      <Spinner show={this.props.ajaxCallsInProgress > 0 && this.state.timerOver} />
    )
}
```